# Changing Header Style in Drupal 7

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7, header

I am trying to change the Header style in a premium theme. As i can see in the live demo there are 5 header style option. And with the theme there are several html files with the 5 header styles. I can see at the theme's css files that there are the 5 styles in the style.css. I can't find any options in the admin menu. Do i have to change something into the css files ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

it seems like I changed it from the page.tpl.php.
change the class and some other things and it kinda worked.
well not entirely ...

I am sure thats not the answer , but its the only solution by now.